# How to use iGPU for moniotors and NVIDIA GPU for my deep learning only?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I got a new DELL OptiPlex 7000 machine with i7-12700 and an NVIDIA 3070 card.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS, and connect a monitor to the machine. Only the NVIDIA card can get me to the Ubuntu GNOME. If I connect the monitor to the motherboard, it is just a black screen with the cursor blinking. Then I tried to connect two monitors, one to the NVIDIA card and one to the motherboard, then both becomes black screens.

I tried to find a solution on the Internet and changed this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.force_probe=4680"
Then bothe screens are on now.
It seems something related to the iGPU drivers and the OS kernel.

I want to use the iGPU for monitors and use the NVIDIA card only for computing.
So, I am wondering what version of Ubuntu should I use to max the performance of both? And how should I config the OS?

Comment: Test your hardware with a 22.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Comment: When I plug in the live USB, the monitor is in a wired green color, I can see the GUI but can barely read. I thought it is because the USB itself has poor quality or the bandwidth is not enough.
I installed the OS though, and after the installation, the machine works fine. My question is more related to how to config the OS so I can use the NVIDIA for computing only but not the gnome and xorg.